# WebAPI MapHttpRoute issue with action parameters of type list and bool

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-web-api-routing

I have a deployment time issue with WebAPI and would be grateful if someone can help.

Routes:

```
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi2",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi3",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{lines}/{swapAxis}",
            defaults: new
            {
                controller = "LVChart",
                action = "Get",
                lines = RouteParameter.Optional, 
                swapAxis = RouteParameter.Optional
            }
        );
    }
```

Action :

```
    // GET api/<controller>
    public IEnumerable<string> Get1()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }
    // GET api/<controller>
    [ActionName("Get")]
    public string Get([FromUri] List<Line> lines, bool swapAxis)
    {
        _lineBuilder = new LVLineBuilder(swapAxis);
        string result = BuildLines(lines);
        return result;
    }
```

OK now here's the problem. 
Both Get1 and Get(..) works well in localhost. However as soon as deployed on server (Note: I am only deploying webpages/js/dll using publishing wizard) Get1 works fine but Get throws "500 Internal Server Error"

The url for Get1 is

```
.../api/LVChart/Get1/
```

While Get is

```
.../api/LVChart/Get/?lines[]=15&lines[]=11&lines[]=12&lines[]=3&lines[]=10&lines[]=7&swapAxis=false
```

I am really running out of options about how to solve this.

Thanks

Comment: Try using a tool like ELMAH to log the error so that you can inspect the stack trace and see exactly what kind of exception is being thrown. 500 Internal Server Error could be any exception thrown from the action method.

Comment: tried doing it but its now showing error for installing elmah... cant believe my luck

Comment: I am suspecting something wrong with my maproute?

Comment: I am starting to think it is the method signature. You are asking for a series of numbers, but the action is expecting a series of Line objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this to work ,I think your custom routes should come above dafault route. i.e DefaultApi2 and DefaultApi3 should come above DefaultApi1.

Also to be RESTfull you can also try avoiding extra default routes and use only default route 1 and do `HttpGet` to `/api/LVChart`, like this

```
.../api/LVChart?lines[]=15&lines[]=11&lines[]=12&lines[]=3&lines[]=10&lines[]=7&swapAxis=false
```